# Application Insights Alert Trigger History

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are using application insights for sending our metrics. Based on these metrics we have alerts set via a customQuery.

The alerts are working fine. I'm expecting to pull data out of the alerts trigger and put use it for analytical purpose.

Explanation:
I have alerts A,B,C,D,E.....
During a course of period A triggered 5 times, B 3 times, D 10 times.....
Now for this course of the period to start with I'm looking at having an insight into which failure happened most frequently so appropriate action can be taken.

Where can I find this information? Not expecting the `Monitor` tab as it gives a very basic view.

Comment: I think you need to get the app insights log itself and run analytics on it. only on the alerts means it is much smaller subset isnt it.

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed steps about how to set metrics alert via custom query? And which data do you wanna fetch?

Comment: @IvanYang https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-log?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json This is where you can see the steps to set alerts based on customQuery. Writing the query entirely depends on the use case and metrics one pushes to insights.
Also, have updated the explanation in the question above to illustrate the data requirement.